# Is it possible to Wake-On-Lan without a router?

Tags: wake-on-lan

If 2 machines are hooked up over a Cat5 (an ad-hoc network?), could one machine WOL another? Does a router/switch have to be in the loop in order for WOL to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

First, if one of your devices is a bit dated (more than 10 years old), you need an [ethernet crossover cable](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) to create a working connection. If both devices support [MDI-X](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface%23Auto_MDI-X) (most modern devices do), you can use a regular ethernet cable. Check your device specification to be sure.

Don't forget to enable WOL in the BIOS of the target machine.

Then you can use whatever tool you want to use to send the WOL magic packet from one computer to the other.

If this doesn't work, you may need to manually configure both NIC's to 100 MB full duplex, because auto negotiation might fail using the crossover.

Googling for "wol crossover" gave me a few links that support this scenario, such as [this server vault item](https://serverfault.com/questions/355852/is-it-possible-to-wake-a-computer-connected-directly-to-its-nic).

Comment: /edit: Fine then. :) A crossover cable is not necessary on “recent” (~10 years) devices, because nearly all of them support Auto MDI-X.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. removed section about IP. Also added remark about MDI-X.

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, Automatic MDI/MDI-X Configuration is an optional feature in the 1000BASE-T standard and I've never seen it without.